# Brute force Caesar Cipher

Tags: python-2.7, caesar-cipher

How do I make my program print the answers on separate lines + with what key the line corresponds to?

```
def break_crypt(message):
    for key in range(1,27):

        for character in message:

            if character in string.uppercase:

                old_ascii=ord(character)
                new_ascii=(old_ascii-key-65)%26+65
                new_char=chr(new_ascii)
                sys.stdout.write(new_char),

            elif character in string.lowercase:

                old_ascii=ord(character)
                new_ascii=(old_ascii-key-97)%26+97
                new_char=chr(new_ascii)
                sys.stdout.write(new_char),

            else:
                sys.stdout.write(character),
```

Comment: do you want the output like- sentence<space>key<newline> ?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you simply add the following at the end of the outer loop, then it'll both print the key and go to the next line:

```
        print '', key
```

Then the output will look like this:

```
Sghr hr z sdrs 1
Rfgq gq y rcqr 2
Qefp fp x qbpq 3
        .
        .
        .
Uijt jt b uftu 25
This is a test 26
```

But I would really build the whole string for the current key in a string variable and then print it at once.

Comment: That's all I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @FredrikEngblom You're welcome. And makes me wonder even more why someone downvoted my answer. Anyway, would you be so kind to mark the answer as accepted then? (or another, if that's more appropriate)

Answer (score 1):

to jump a line simply use "\n"
for instance:

```
sys.stdout.write("a\nb")
```

will write a and b in differents lines

use + to add a string to another

```
sys.stdout.write("a"+variable+"b")
```

there is other "more advanced" ways like

```
sys.stdout.write("a%sb" % variable)
```

or

```
sys.stdout.write("a{0}b".format(variable)
```

also in your code if there is no point of using sys.stdout.write don't use it

this may helps you
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html